# Embed an iFrame Tweet into Google Slides

Tags: html, google-slides

Hello I tried to embed this HTML code into a Google Slide but I am encountering problems, does anyone know how to do so?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/p0rkboi/hy31kr0a/7/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately at this time you can not do that. However Google is constantly updating this stuff, so it may be possible in the future.

But Here you can use http://slides.com/. You can add iframe in your presentation.

Comment: do you know any other tool , with which we can embed, like a add-on or something else.